# Authorization error when connecting an app to a service

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm following https://github.com/ibm/predictive-model-on-watson-ml

Created the app (step 1) and the ML service (step 2).

The instruction is: Verify this service is being created in the same space as the app in Step 1, and click Create.

That was not possible, I could only choose a resource group, default or my own.

Wenn I try to connect the app in an org/space to the service I get the error:

[403, Forbidden] You are not authorized to perform the requested action

Answer (score 0):

@jpsstack can you/did you try changing the region? i.e. from Washington to Dallas. That should give new org and space opt